# C++ pthread'ed process running slower than single thread issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, pthreads

I was trying to run a function on multiple pthreads in order to increase efficiency and runtime. This function performs a lot of matrix calculations and print statements. However, when I ran tests in order see the performance improvement, the single threaded code ran faster.

My tests went as follows:

-For the single-threaded: Run a for loop 1:1000 that called the function.

-For the multi-pthreaded: Spawn 100 pthreads, have a queue of 1000 items and a     pthread_cond_wait and have the threads run the function until the queue is empty.

Here is my code for the pthreads (single-threaded is just a for loop instead):

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <queue>

using namespace std;
# define NUM_THREADS 100

int main ( );
queue<int> testQueue;
void *playQueue(void* arg);
void matrix_exponential_test01 ( );
void matrix_exponential_test02 ( );
pthread_mutex_t queueLock;
pthread_cond_t queue_cv;

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_mutex_init(&queueLock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&queue_cv, NULL);

    for( int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ )
    {
       pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, playQueue, (void*)NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock (&queueLock);
    for(int z=0; z<1000; z++)
    {
        testQueue.push(1);
        pthread_cond_signal(&queue_cv);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&queueLock);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&queueLock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&queue_cv);
    pthread_cancel(NULL);*/
    return 0;
}


void* playQueue(void* arg)
{
bool accept;
while(true)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cv, &queueLock);
    accept = false;
    if(!testQueue.empty())
    {
        testQueue.pop();
        accept = true;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&queueLock);
    if(accept)
    {
        runtest();
    }
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

My intuition tells me that the multi-threaded version should run faster, but it doesnt. Is there a reason, or is my code faulty? I am using C++ on Windows, and had to download a library to use pthreads.

Comment: Your `playQueue` is declared to return a pointer, but the code doesn't return any value. That's undefined behaviour. Also, you have a `*/` in your code without matching `/*` Also, do you have 100 cpu's (cores)? If not, even if your program was parallel, most of those threads would be waiting in queue and wasting synchronization overhead.

Comment: `playQueue` doesn't actually do any work. You are measuring pure overhead of creating and tearing down threads.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sorry I mis-copied, but I editted the question. The thread is supposed to perform the function runtest() which has all the math in it.

Comment: Before worrying about making your program fast, you need to make it correct. There are two sources of undefined behavior: (1) `playQueue` calls [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) without locking the mutex first, and (2) `main` destroys the mutex and condition variable without waiting for the threads to finish.

Comment: You should not run a lot of threads. 100 is almost always excessive. Try to run a little more threads than you have cores (i.e. on Linux result of `grep processor /proc/cpuinfo| wc -l`...). So try with 5, 10, 15 and 20 threads.

Answer (score 5):

First, your code is written in a way that only one thread will run at any time (your mutex is locked the whole time the thread is doing work). So at **best** you can expect your Code to be as fast as the single threaded version.

Also, all threads reading and writing the same memory each time. This way you force your CPU cores to synchronize their caches, meaning actually **more** load on the bus than would be caused by a single thread. Since you are not doing any computationally expensive stuff, it is likely that memory bandwidth is your actual bottleneck and thus the bus load added by cache synchronization slows down your program. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing for more information.

Comment: I made an edit to the question as I forgot a major part, which was the function it called. So the function runtest() is where all the math occurs, so it should be able to run on its own. The only time the mutex is locked is when it updates the queue.

Comment: Depending on how much time the tests take, this may still be the same problem. If your test can be performed with little to no memory accesses, the test may be still too fast to make any difference. One core can do hundreds of arithmetic instructions while another one is using the memory bus. In that case, your program would run about exactly as fast, no matter whether you have the test included or not.

Answer (score 4):

If `runtest()` is CPU-bound -- that is, doesn't do anything which might block on i/o or the like -- then there's not much point starting 100 threads, unless you have 100 cpus/cores !  [Edit: I now notice that `runtest()` does some print statements... file i/o probably won't block... so won't release the CPU.]

The code as currently shown holds the mutex while filling the queue, so nothing will start until the queue is full.  By the time filling of the queue has finished signalling 1000 times, if any have reached the `pthread_cond_wait()`, then hopefully they will all have been started -- so all 100 will be waiting on the mutex.

As currently shown the waiting in `playQueue()` is broken.  It should be something along the lines of:

```
  pthread_mutex_wait(&queueLock) ;

  while (testQueue.empty)
    pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cv, &queueLock) ;

  if (testQueue.eof)
    val = NULL ;
  else
    val = testQueue.pop ;

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueLock) ;
```

But, even when this is all sorted out, there is no guarantee you will see an improvement in performance, unless `runtest()` does a serious amount of work.  [Edit: I now notice that it does "a lot of matrix calculations", which sounds like it could be plenty of work.]

One small suggestion, starting the worker threads and filling the queue could be overlapped, by (for instance) starting one worker with the job of starting all the others, or starting a thread to fill the queue.

Without knowing more about the problem, if the work can be statically divided across the worker threads -- for instance, give the first thread items 0..9, the second thread items 10..19, and so on -- so each worker can ignore all the others, reducing the amount of synchronisation operations.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other good answers, you said your `runtest()` function does I/O.

So you could well be I/O bound, in which case all your threads have to wait in line like everybody else to empty out their buffers.